# How to put a limit on memory usage while parsing a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, org.json

How can I rule out a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when calling

```
new JSONObject(longAndMalformedJSONString)
```

I'm using the org.json implementation of a JSON parser.

I'm not looking for a way to decode the bad JSON String. I just want to put an upper limit on memory usage (and possibly CPU usage) and maybe get an exception that I can recover from.

Or, alternatively, is it safe to say, memory usage while parsing will never exceed a certain ratio compared to input string length? Then I could just limit that.

Or is there an alternate library that offers that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches when reading serialized data (JSON, XML, whatever): you either parse the entire input and keep the object in memory, or you navigate the stream via the provided API and you just keep the pieces you are interested in. It seems org.json doesn't have a streaming API, but more sophisticated libraries like [Gson do](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming):

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
  Message message = gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
  messages.add(message);
}
reader.endArray();
reader.close();
```

You can also also put limits on the input, but it depends on the protocol you use for transferring the JSON payload

Comment: Is there a way to parse the entire input and keep the object in memory, while imposing a maximum size on the generated object? (And on depth of recursion for that matter) It doesn't seem possible with the org.json library. I don't want to use a streaming library.

Comment: I don't think so. By the way, if you deserilize the JSON into some Java class definition, the maximum depth of the object graph is constrainted by the types used for the mapping